# Does the ledger board for a bathtub go under the flange or level with it?

Tags: framing, bathtub

Replacing a bathtub with a new one pictured.  It will go into a 3-walled space.  Durock and tile will be attached to wall to finish the job.

I've been reading many articles and they mention a ledger board for tub support.

I drew a picture.  Is the ledger board supposed to be under the flange side (as pictured in black) or do you nail the flange to the ledger board (which means I'd have to shim all the studs to be flush)?

[image: the tub]

Comment: Why would you want to make holes through the flange by nailing through it?

Comment: @Michael Karas  I have not bought the tub yet.  However, it looks like these tubs get attched to the wall via nail holes or clips.  Unless I am wrong???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tub should have clear and specific instructions. It varies by model and material.

However, if a ledger board is used, it'll be under the flange, providing support from below. There's no point to a ledger if you have a typical framed wall and can simply nail the flange to the studs every 16".

The only tubs I've ever installed using a ledger are large spa-type tubs, and those are usually set into a full deck. Typical shower tubs simply get fastened to the wall framing. *Do follow the instructions, though, or you'll void your warranty.*

Comment: If the flange does need to be nailed, be sure to predrill the holes since a nail can easily cause the flange to crack, or break. You also want to use coated fasteners that are rust resistant.

Comment: Yes, 2" roofing nails might be a good choice. Do drill accordingly, but _only_ if indicated by the manufacturer to do so.